# Java usage of static declarations in generics

Tags: java, generics

I am confused on the following:

I want to do:

```
public class MyGenericClass<SomeType> extends SomeMoreAbstractClass<SomeType>{
    private Node<SomeType> beginNode;
    private static final Node<SomeType> NOT_FOUND = null;

    private static class Node<SomeType>{  
     //class definition here
    }
}
```

I.e. I want to use the `NOT_FOUND` in the code in checks for `null`

I get the error `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type AnyType`
in the line that I declare `private static final Node<SomeType> NOT_FOUND = null;`

How can I get arround this? I prefer to use it as a class variable and not an instance variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply declare the field as

```
private static final Node<?> NOT_FOUND = null;
```

As it's static, it will be shared between all instances of `MyGenericClass`, so it can't refer to `SomeType` which is a type parameter specified per class instance. `Node<?>` makes it compatible with all possible type parameters. It is then not useful for anything that depends on a specific type parameter, but fortunately, comparison with `null` still works.

Comment: You can assign any parameterisation of `Node<>` to that non-variable variable.

Comment: If I use it as a return from a method e.g. `private Node<SomeType> search(Object o){.....return NOT_FOUND}` `Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyGenericClass.Node<capture#2-of ?> to MyGenericClass.Node<SomeType>`. I have to explicitely cast

Comment: @user384706: That leaves the option of using the raw type `Node`, which will result in unchecked warnings. I'm afraid there is really no entirely clean way of doing this, as it goes against the type system, and the only reason it can work at all is that the value is null.

Answer (score 6):

You need to remove the `static` modifiers. Generics are, by definition, coupled to the concrete object. It is not possible to have `static` (= identical for all objects) members, that have a generic parameter.

Don't forget that `SomeType` is just a placeholder for what ever class you use, when you instanciate the object. (like this: `MyGenericClass<Integer> x = new MyGenericClass<Integer>();`)

Comment: Of couse can you have static member with generic parameters: `public static <T> void method(T parameter) { ... }`

Comment: @Oliver: but that's a generica parameter for that particular method, not for the class.